# (Java) Error parsing google directions XML using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, google-directions-api

I'm trying to get driving directions between two locations using the google directions api.

I have tried to parse the XML returned using different methods but I am always receiving the following error.

javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

//code redacted

Comment: Perhaps there are characters in front of the XML declaration? Please show your code and the XML document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the code to the question.

Comment: Did it occur to you that you are trying to parse JSON as if it were XML? [This is the page that is fetched](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&origin=nottingham&destination=derby) - it's definitely not XML and XPath cannot be used to navigate it.

Comment: Replace `json` in `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json` with `xml` and it should return XML.

Comment: Oh dear, I did not notice at all. The URL was provided by my tutor and he told me to use XML parsing so I did not think to check it. Thank you. Replacing JSON with XML removed the error, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we have established that's indeed the only problem, I'm adding it as an answer.

The page you request is not XML, but JSON. The SAX parser returns an error because the parser input is not a well-formed XML document. It doesn't have to be, since it's valid JSON.

As suggested by @geert3, just replace `json` with `xml` in the URL:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&origin=nottingham&destination=derby
```

Or else, [parse JSON with a JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) and use [JSONPath](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/) instead of XPath to query it.